# Issue building Qt libraries in Qt Creator (Windows)

Tags: android, qt, serial-port, qt-creator

I'm experiencing an issue with Qt Creator in Windows:

I made an application that is using QtSerialPort and QtSerialBus libraries, I built and deployed it for windows and everything went well.
Now I'm trying to built it for Android but those libraries are not available as the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html) states.

I downloaded the sources of QtSerialPort and QtSerialBus from Github and I'm now trying to build  them by myself for Android.
AFAIK the issue I'm encountering is in the make install step, and this is the message I get:

```
08:05:28: Starting: "C:\Android\ndk-bundle\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" "INSTALL_ROOT=C:\Users\giovanni.lucenti\Downloads\qtserialport\android-build" install
cd src\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.14.2\android\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Users\giovanni.lucenti\Downloads\qtserialport-dev\src\src.pro -spec android-clang "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler" "ANDROID_ABIS=armeabi-v7a" ) && C:/Android/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/giovanni.lucenti/Downloads/qtserialport/src'
cd serialport\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.14.2\android\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Users\giovanni.lucenti\Downloads\qtserialport-dev\src\serialport\serialport.pro -spec android-clang "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler" "ANDROID_ABIS=armeabi-v7a" ) && C:/Android/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make -f Makefile install
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/giovanni.lucenti/Downloads/qtserialport/src/serialport'
La sintassi del nome del file, della directory o del volume non Š corretta.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:639: install_target] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/giovanni.lucenti/Downloads/qtserialport/src/serialport'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:59: sub-serialport-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/giovanni.lucenti/Downloads/qtserialport/src'
make: *** [Makefile:61: sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
08:05:30: The process "C:\Android\ndk-bundle\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qtserialport (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.14.2 for Android))
When executing step "Copy application data"
08:05:30: Elapsed time: 00:23.
```

I already tried to move the folder in a shorter path (C:\tmpbuild) but everything goes the same.
Am I missing something?
Where am I supposed to set the make install target path?
These are my [Qt Creator build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9E5r.jpg)

Comment: The error message is in italian, I'm sorry. The meaning is: "The Filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use QSerialPort on Android, as it is not suported there.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not explaining the errore message I'm receiving. Furthermore, I was able to build qtserialport "by accident" and it's working on my phone but I can't repeat the success. And can't do the same for qtserialbus also

Comment: 1. I will repeat again: QtSerialPort does nt supported on Android, and it does not work there without of the root rights. So, you should use it with own risk.

2. QtSerialBus compiles on Android without of QSerialPort support. In this case you will able to communicate only with Modbus over TCP/IP.

Comment: Ok, I'll tell my PC that QtSerialBus compile despite the log is telling me the opposite.